# How do I set abritrary labels on a second Calc chart axis?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I'm graphing a value by hour over a 24-hour period. One column in my spreadsheet is the integer hour-of-the-day, UTC time; another column is the value itself. I can turn that into a line graph or scatterplot easily enough.

I want to add a secondary X-axis showing the corresponding hour-of-the-day in local time. I have the corresponding hour numbers in another column, generated with something like `=MOD(A2+N, 24)`. So, something like:

```
utc_hr  local_hr  value
0       22        514
1       23        16135
2       0         2288
3       1         4121
```

...and so on.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to properly label the secondary axis. Or how to do anything useful with the secondary axis at all.

Specific things I've looked for and couldn't find:

- A way to dynamically generate axis labels with something like MOD(val+N, 24).
- An option in the axis format to label it from a range.
- Overlaying two graphs on the same chart.
- An option for data series that lets you pick the axis to graph them against. I could make that work by duping the series. This option actually exists! But only for the Y axis, which doesn't help me.

I tried all of the above, and probably more, with both line graphs and XY scatters. No luck. Help?